# MySQLUser administration deny access

Tags: mysql, datatable, privileges, database-administration, user-management

I like to deny the change and creating of tables for a specific users.
So I searched for setting such privileges, but I've found nothing about it.

how can I archive these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and you can find out more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-management-sql.html. In MySQL these privileges are stored in the MySQL > table_privs table.

Comment: OK, great. I think that's it.

Comment: Cool - if that fixes it please set it as the answer :o) Always helps. Thanks.